# How do I integrate a google maps with all the places and informations in my android app? Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps, android-layout, android-fragments, android-studio, dictionary

i need to have more places that appears on the map because i’m developing a restaurant booking app and no restaurant appears in the whole city on the other hand when i’m using google maps app i can see all the places and related informationshow can i have a full info google map on my app
Screen
[Google map screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbg8w.jpg)

Comment: you should first read the google maps api in google developer website . you will get the basic idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can read through the [Official Google Documentation of API for Android](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start). This guide introduces the features in the Google Places for Android and shows you how to configure your app to use the API.

The main entry points for the Google Places API for Android are the [PlacePicker](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/ui/PlacePicker.html) UI widget, the [Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete) UI widget, the [GeoDataApi](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/GeoDataApi.html), and the [PlaceDetectionApi](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/P).

Using the Google API for Android, you can build location-aware apps that respond contextually to the local businesses and other places near the device. This means that you can build rich apps based on places that mean something to the user, to complement the straightforward geographic-based services offered by the [Android location services][6] you pass a general search term, Google Maps will attempt to find a location near the lat/lng you specified that matches your criteria. If no location is specified, Google Maps will try to find nearby listings. For example:

```
// Search for restaurants nearby
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=restaurants");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(mapIntent);

// Search for restaurants in San Francisco
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:37.7749,-122.4194?q=restaurants");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(mapIntent);
```